# What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$?

Tags: real-numbers

I know that both of them contain all positive numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ but one notation contains $0$ too. I don't know which one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_real_numbers for the different existing notations.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}^*$ might typically be the whole set excluding $0$  but keeping negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb R^+ = \{r\in \Bbb R\mid r>0\}$ (open half space) and $\Bbb R^* = \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ (carrier set of multiplicative group of field $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Be careful, it depends on convention/languages : $\mathbb{R}^+$ sometimes stands for $\lbrace r \in \mathbb{R}, r\geq 0 \rbrace$, in which case we write $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ for $\lbrace r \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes indeed, in fact I recall writing $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ in highschool in France 40 years ago.

Comment: @user3733558 ... and this notation is still used today in France :)